# When should a Django logging instance be created?

Tags: python, django, logging

Should a `logging` instance whose runtime configuration will never be altered be created (via `getLogger`) inside of each function that uses it, or can I create it once and only once outside of the functions?

Example:

```
import logging

def homepage_view(...):
  log = logging.getLogger(...)
  log.debug('Loaded the homepage')
```

or

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(...)

def homepage_view(...):
  log.debug('Loaded the homepage')
```

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second of these is the recommended best practice, using

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

at the module level.

**Update:** It's the best practice because it's simpler. Nothing is gained by invoking `getLogger` in each function that uses it, and loggers are singletons anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Why is this the best practice?